# Dependency Injection for third party data context in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET core Web API, I need to use MongoDb. Following is my implementation so far but I am stuck in resolving dependencies.

**DataContext:**

```
 public class AppDbContext
    {
        public IMongoDatabase MongoDatabase { get; set; }
        public AppDbContext()
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            MongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase("cse-dev-db");
        }
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
public class BuyRepository: IBuyRepository {
    private readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;
    public BuyRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext) {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }
    public Buy Add(Buy buy) {
        _appDbContext.MongoDatabase.GetCollection<Buy("Buy").InsertOne(buy);
        return buy;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
private readonly BuyRepository _buyRepository;
public ValuesController(BuyRepository buyRepository) {
    _buyRepository = buyRepository;
}
```

My question is how to add this dependencies in `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    services.AddMvc();
    // How to add dependencies here
}
```

**PS:** I have already seen [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1267/using-mongodb-nosql-database-with-aspnet-webapi-core) but it does not work.

## Update

I have tried as per comment by a user

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
            services.AddScoped<AppDbContext>();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddScoped<IBuyRepository, BuyRepository>();
        }
```

Now I am getting following exception

> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'CseApi.Repositories.BuyRepository' while attempting to activate
> 'CseApi.Controllers.ValuesController'.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is not working I need to check it manually. It strange that mongo db post article which is not tested.

Comment: Are you using a NuGet package to add support for MongoDB?

Comment: Yes `"mongocsharpdriver": "2.3.0"`

Comment: It's throwing exception. Please see my updated question

Comment: You need to inject the interface `IBuyStockRepository` in the `ValuesController` constructor, not the concrete type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to register services like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
    services.AddScoped<AppDbContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IBuyRepository, BuyRepository>();
    services.AddMvc();
    // How to add dependencies here
}
```

**Update for comment**

Controller code should be something like below:

```
private readonly IBuyRepository _buyRepository;
public ValuesController(IBuyRepository buyRepository) {
    _buyRepository = buyRepository;
}
```

Comment: It's throwing exception `Unable to resolve service for type 'CseApi.Repositories.BuyRepository' while attempting to activate 'CseApi.Controllers.ValuesController'`

Comment: Your controller should take `IBuyRepository` not `BuyRepository`. See my update.

Comment: Yes That was the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update your controller's injection from this:

```
private readonly BuyRepository _buyRepository;
```

to this:

```
private readonly IBuyRepository _buyRepository;
```